# Which is the best lightweight jquery plugin to make cross browser round corner without using image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Round corner should be compatible with all **IE versions** also.

From one plugin i want to make round corner button, text input field, round corner tab, round corner div, round corner table etc.

Although i use http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/

but it has slow rendering in IE8 and i thought if I'm already using jquery library then to use any jquery plugin would be better and lighter.

Comment: Yes it should be compatible with IE6-7, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari.  Is that your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a new project I just came across http://jquery.malsup.com/corner today. It looks to work fine in all of the browsers. See if it suits your needs as well.

**Edit**: to add some extra information, I also came across the following solutions:
http://dev.jquery.com/~paul/plugins/nifty/example.html
http://blue-anvil.com/jquerycurvycorners/test.html

Both however didn't satisfy me. Either the width/height got messed up, or transparency didn't work well, or the floats got mad. There are more, but they either uses images, or have dependencies, or have opaque source code / documentation, or have the same problems with width/height/floats.

Comment: Does IE 8 has any pure css way to make round corner?

Comment: IE8 doesn't support the CSS3 `border-radius` property yet, no.

Comment: Do u use this script for all browser or only for IE? and can we write one conditional comment for all IE version till 8?

Comment: This script automatically detects the browser and applies the right technique. Just use it for all browsers. No worries. Check the source, it's open source (doh =) ). Just try it out. It's easy: `$(element).corner();` for default rounded corners.

Comment: but if we will use css only for all border-radius supported browsers then at least we can show round corner on those browsers even if JavaScript is disabled

Comment: You can surely add the extra CSS yourself. Most browsers other than IE will support it. You only need to ensure that you apply the same radius in the `corner()`.

Comment: @Jitendra: Why not just try it for yourself and find out – I just tried it and it takes ~5 minutes.

Comment: @BalusC so malsup is best yet

Comment: That's my opinion. You're free to try them all.