# Is there any other better way than this (modernizr 7 KB javascript) to make round corner for IE 6, IE 7, IE 8?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#borderradius **only 8KB in size.**

Comment: When you edit your question, I'd leave the actual question in there.

Comment: You've asked similar question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774457/which-is-the-best-lightweight-jquery-plugin-to-make-cross-browser-round-corner-wi Did you forgot it? :)

Comment: BalusC - yes but that is a different question of jquery.

Answer (score 4):

Modernizr doen't round corners, that's not what the library is about:

Modernizr is a small JavaScript library that detects the availability of native implementations for next-generation web technologies. With this knowledge that Modernizr gives you, you can take advantage of these new features in the browsers that can render or utilize them, and still have easy and reliable means of creating fallbacks.

These fallbacks are not part of the library.

Comment: what's its use if it doesnt implement fallbacks ?

Comment: @tada: Modernizr is used to load the polyfills (or fallbacks) that you want to use when a feature (such as rounded corners) is missing in the browser. That means that if you're using a modern browser that supports one particular feature then you don't need to load the polyfill.

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying out CurvyCorners:

http://www.curvycorners.net/

I like the concept, as it is set up to only round elements that already have a corner-radius CSS value, so is really easy to implement and completely unobtrusive.

However, I'm having some issues with it conflicting with some of the jQuery UI elements.

For now, we're opting to just give IE square corners.

Comment: I agree with DA. Use CSS round corners if available. And leave square corners for IE and Opera.
You could even consider square corners in IE and Opera as a graceful degradation ;)

Comment: good plugin, works great for me

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Spiffy Corners](http://www.spiffycorners.com/). It's all CSS, but it makes the CSS a little
 heavy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this — http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/

Comment: I checked. size is same but modernizer has some more benefits in same size

Comment: ie-css3.htc file is not compressed, if you do it the file size will decrease to 4-5kb

Comment: Modernizr only does detection. It doesn't make things work if they aren't natively supported.